# Displaying an objects properties different from default behavior in form helper rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I go about displaying the `:cords` property below as a formatted array itself? and not just it's values. Given the form below:

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :cords %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :cords, name: "group[cords]" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :members %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :members %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

When editing the object, I'd get something like

[image]

But what I **want** to see is the full raw data, like so:

[image]

I think this can be done with `to_s`, but i'm not sure how to go about getting this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an `input` tag instead `text_field` helper:

```
<input type="text" name="group[cords]" value="<%= group.cords %>">
```